# How to disable device mapper for live.iso?

Tags: linux, livecd, device-mapper

I made a live.iso by `livemedia-creator`. I use it to make livecd. However, when I boot it, the disk(/dev/sda) is always controlled by /dev/mapper. I want to make my iso boot without /dev/mapper enabled. Is there any advice please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can disable device mapper by `dracut`.

| https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/dracut.cmdline.7.html

[image]